# Polymer paper-date-picker, why only quoted date property works?

Tags: polymer

[paper-date-picker](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker/) is working **only** when date is in quotes, as:

```
<paper-date-picker date='{{"some_data.date"}}'></paper-date-picker>
```

and this is not working:

```
   <paper-date-pickerdate='{{some_data.date}}'></paper-date-picker>
```

What difference does the quotes make?

Value of some_data.date is string:

```
date: "2015-03-25"
```

Comment: The quotes don't make any sense. What do you mean by "not working" exactly anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The `<paper-date-picker>` `date` property seems to expect a `new Date(...)` instead of a string.